# error 500 on google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I am trying to create a servlet on the Google App Engine. I have done this sucsessfully a few times in the past, but now I get an "Internal Server Error" when running it from the cloud.

It works on Eclipse on development mode, though.

My servlet is called AsyncServer and the code is:

```
public class AsyncServer extends HttpServlet {
static final long serialVersionUID=0L;

  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
      resp.setContentType("text/plain");
      PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
      writer.write("Hello");
      writer.flush();
      writer.close();
}

  @Override
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {}
```

}

I use the following address to call it on the local development server:

http://127.0.0.1:8888/test4/AsyncServer

and I get "Hello", as expected.

When deployed to the Google servers under the ID fa100-1130
I use the following address

http://fa100-1130.appspot.com/test4/AsyncServer

I get an http error 500

Comment: What do the logs show? You can look at them on the Google Developers Console -- https://console.developers.google.com

Comment: Thanks, that may be it. The log has several errors like this:

Comment: Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/tests/test4/server/AsyncServer : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 - What is that?

Comment: Solver thanks to Alex Martelli. I was using Java version 1.8 and downgraded it ti 1.7 and all worked.

Comment: Always glad to help -- please remember in the future to always look at the logs and include them in questions!-) Now if you could post your resolution as an answer and eventually accept it that would be great, marking the Q as resolved by stackoverflow's rules...!

Answer (score 0):

Currently entering the URL mentioned in your question and returns an affirmative respesta:
http://fa100-1130.appspot.com/test4/AsyncServer

[image: http://fa100-1130.appspot.com/test4/AsyncServer]

run the development and performs deploy again

bye :) @locoalien

Comment: It was already fixed as per Alex Martelli's suggestion to read the logs. I downgraded from java 1.8 to 1.7 as suggested by the logs "Unsupported version". I understood from other posts that some functions on the GAE on the cloud may not be compatible with the latest versions of java.